# Have given width and height of every div in percentage but it is only working with large screen devices and divs are overlapping otherwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Have set height and width of every div in percentage. Working fine on large screen laptops but overlapping when the website is opened in small screen devices. Also many div's position is set to be relative, is this the problem?

Comment: Giving us a some code examples helps a lot in troubleshooting your issue!

Comment: Hi Rohit. Would you mind posting some code?

Comment: My guess is that divs contain some content and `overflow:hidden` is not set

Comment: #general
{
 position: relative; /* or absolute */ 
  top: -75%;
  left: 55%;
width:40%;

}
#topic
{
position: relative; /* or absolute */
  top: 0%;
  left:5%;
width:40%;

}